# Can a number like $101$, $10001$ or $1001$ have a square factor?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can a number of the form $10^m + 1$ have a square factor?

$$10^m + 1 = a c^2$$

How might I go about showing there is no such number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One very elementary way in which one might discover the solution offered by **JMoravitz** is to notice that the usual test for divisibility by $11$ makes it easy to see that $10^n+1$ is a multiple of $11$ if and only if $n$ is odd, so we might investigate numbers of the form $\frac{10^{2m+1}+1}{11}$ to see whether it’s easy to determine whether any of them can be multiples of $11$. Now

$$10^{2m+1}+1=1\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{2m}1\;,$$

and it’s not hard to verify by induction on $m$ that

$$\frac{10^{2m+1}+1}{11}=\underbrace{9090\ldots9091}_{2m}=1+90\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}10^{2k}\;.$$

This is divisible by $11$ if and only if the alternating sum of its digits is divisible by $11$, and that alternating sum is $9m-1$, so we want positive integer solutions to $9m-1=11n$. By inspection $m=5,n=4$ is a solution, so the [general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation) to this Diophantine equation is

$$m=5+11k,n=4+9k$$

for integer $k$, where only those with $k\ge 0$ are relevant to this problem. The next larger multiple of $11^2$ of the form $10^{2m+1}+1$ is therefore $10^{2\cdot16+1}+1=10^{33}+1$, with $k=1$ and $m=16$.

Answer (score 9):

Yes: [$11^2\cdot 23\cdot 4093\cdot 8779=10^{11}+1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11%5E2*23*4093*8779)

Comment: And infinitely many more.

Comment: including $7^2|10^{21}+1$

Comment: As for infinitely more, yes... if $a^2\mid 10^k+1$, then $10^k\equiv -1\pmod{a^2}$ and so $10^{(2n+1)k}\equiv (-1)^{2n+1}\equiv -1\pmod{a^2}$, i.e. knowing $11^2\mid 10^{11}+1$ we get for free that $11^2\mid 10^{33}+1$ and $10^{55}+1$ etc...

Comment: another is $13^2\mid10^{39}+1$

Comment: If someone wants to take it further and describe all $p$ such that $-1\in\langle 10\rangle$ in $\Bbb Z_{p^2}^\times$, that could effectively give an answer to the full list of such $10^k+1$ who are not square-free.  Obviously $2$ and $5$ are out since $2\mid 10^k$ and $5\mid 10^k$ for all $k>0$., so too is $3$ since $10\equiv 1\pmod{3^2}$.  I am admittedly weak when it comes to things like quadratic reciprocity, but it might well be the case that for every prime $p$ other than those three we can find a $k$ such that $10^k+1$ is divisible by $p^2$

Comment: @JMoravitz I would be interested to know whether it's provable that $31^2{|}\,(10^k+1)$ for some $k.$ (Computation shows $k>10^6$ if such a $k$ exists.)

Comment: A quick check reveals that $31\not\mid 10^n+1$ for any $n$, let alone $31^2$.  We get an issue whenever the base-10 repetend of $1/p$ has odd length.  We were just lucky with even repetend lengths up to and including $p=29$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there are solutions.  And, there are infinitely many of them.

To get the solutions we cleverly use the Binomial Theorem.  Start off, innocuously, with

$10=11-1$

Now raise this to the $11$th power expanding the right side with the theorem:

$10^{11}=11^{11}-(11×11^{10})+(55×11^9)-...+(11×11)-1$

All terms on the right are multiples of $11^2$ except the $-1$ which we transfer and prove the solution noted by JMoravitz:

$11^2|(10^{11}+1)$

Now try, as a slightly more sophisticated example, this initial difference:

$10^3=1001-1$

With $11$, above, which is prime, we just raised to that power.  With $1001$ we have a composite number, and we can choose to raise to any power whose exponent is a(n odd) factor of $1001$.  We can choose an exponent of $7$:

$10^{21}=1001^{7}-(7×1001^{6})+(21×1001^5)-...+(7×1001)-1$

$7^2|(10^{21}+1)$

Or an exponent of $13$:

$10^{39}=1001^{13}-(13×1001^{12})+(78×1001^{11})-...+(13×1001)-1$

$13^2|(10^{39}+1)$

Or even $11$:

$10^{33}=1001^{11}-(11×1001^{10})+(55×1001^{9})-...+(11×1001)-1$

$11^2|(10^{33}+1)$

This relation, of course, follows directly from the earlier result $11^2|(10^{11}+1)$ because $(10^{11}+1)|(10^{33}+1)$.  This correlates with $10^1+1=11$ being a factor of $10^3+1=1001$.  Similarly, if we use a composite exponent like $77$, we get a result corresponding to various factorizations:

$77^2|(10^{231}+1)$ corresponds to $11^2|(10^{11}+1)$ and $7^2|(10^{21}+1)$

You can start with

$10^m=(10^m+1)-1$.

By raising to powers whose exponents are odd factors of $10^m+1$, you can generate solutions for any positive whole number $m$. For instance, with $m=8$ we could raise to the power of $17$, which divides $10^8+1$, and thus render $17^2|10^{136}+1$ (this is the minimal solution with an even power of $10$). Thus **infinitely many solutions**.

Comment: Nice +1; so $17^2\mid10^{136}+1$

Comment: Exactly.  Which happens to be the minimal solution with an even power of 10.

Comment: You seem to be using the inductive step in [lifting the exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma). Implying, among other things, that if $p\mid 10^k+1$, then $p^2\mid 10^{pk}+1$. +1 of course, just wanted to link LTE here also (a variant of this question appeared today).