# Non-squarefree numbers of the form $10^n + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

Consider numbers of the form $10^k + 1$. We can look at the prime factorisation of these numbers and note that the smallest such number that has a repeated prime factor is $10^{11} + 1 = 11^2\cdot{}23\cdot{}4093\cdot{}8779$. We can use this to form a number of the form $a = a_1a_2\dots{}a_ka_1a_2\dots{}a_k$ such that $a$ is a perfect square (the smallest such number is $1322314049613223140496 = 36363636364^2$).

The next smallest number of the form $10^{k} + 1$ with a squared prime factor is $10^{21} + 1 = 7^2\cdot{}11\cdot{}13\cdot{}127\cdot{}2689\cdot{}459691\cdot{}909091$ which can be used to form perfect squares with repeated digits in a similar fashion. Following that comes $10^{33} + 1$, again divisible by $121$ and then $10^{39} + 1$, divisible by $169$.

OEIS contains the sequence [A086981](https://oeis.org/A086981), for which $s(n)$ comprises the smallest value of $k$ for which $10^k + 1$ is divisible by $p_n^2$, where  $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number. Obviously numbers of our special form are not divisible by $2, 3$, or $5$ so the sequence starts $0, 0, 0, 21, 11, 39$.

For some primes $> 5$, the sequence contains a zero, indicating (quoting) no such $k$ exists. The first entry that is not trivially zero is the $11^{\mathrm{th}}$, corresponding to 31. Following that are 37, 41 and 43. The next entry is $1081$ and indeed $10^{1081} + 1$ is divisible by 2209.

Does the "no such $k$" wording mean that *necessarily* no such $k$ exists, or that no *known* $k$ exists? I have checked for *e.g.* divisibility by $41^2$ up to $k$ = several million just for fun.

Comment: From where are you quoting "no such $k$ exists"?

Comment: For $p\nmid 10$, the residue class of $10^k+1$ modulo $p^2$ is periodic with period $p(p-1)$, by Euler's theorem. So it's a finite computation to determine whether or not such a $k$ exists.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3601792/11619) is related but not a good duplicate target at all.

Comment: You need only to check whether $p|10^n+1$ for some $n$, which corresponds with $1/p$ having an **even repeated length** base $10$. Iff this holds then there are also powers of $10$ plus $1$ divisible by $p^2$ (and higher powers of $p$). For instance $1/31$ has a repetend length of $15$, so $31$ fails; but $1/17$ has a repetend length of $16$ so $17$ hits.

Comment: That's a cute observation @OscarLanzi.

Comment: @GregMartin  Surely the period of the residue class mod $p^2$ is a divisor of $p(p-1)$, for example the residue class mod $11^2$ has a period of $22$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first thing that comes to mind:  for a prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$  we know $-1$   is not a quadratic residue.   Therefore, if $10$   is a quadratic residue, it is impossible to have $10^k \equiv -1 \pmod q$  Let me work up some examples.  Meanwhile, $3, 27,  31, 39 \pmod {40} $  primes make the task impossible

There are other ways for $10$  to fail to be a primitive root $\pmod p.$  For instance, the powers of $10$ taken $\pmod {41}$  are, in order  $1, 10, 18, 16, 37, 1, 10, 18, 16, 37,... $  forever. That is, although $-1$  certainly is a residue $\pmod {41},$ we get the premature  $10^5  \equiv 1 \pmod {41},$  only five values occur in this subgroup (of the multiplicative group  which has $40$ elements)

Anyway, it was not necessary  to check $p=41$  for large exponents.  Just check exponents up to $p-2$   and check for an early 1.

Up to 335, the primes that are ruled out by these methods are

three mod 4:

$$  3,   31,   43,   67,   71,   79,   83,  107,  151,  163,  191,  199,  227,  239,  271,  283,  307,  311,  $$

one mod 4

$$  37,   41,   53,  173,  277,  317, $$

Comment: Specifically, for $p = 41$ what we *don't* get is $10^k \equiv -1\bmod{p}$ before $10^k \equiv 1\bmod{p}$ (or contain -1 at all), is this correct?

Comment: @DavidG  yes. ..

Comment: @DavidG,   please calculate $10^k \pmod {37}  $   for small $k$   and your  $10^k \pmod {41}  .$   Next $53.$    It is nice that a simple calculation can decide your question for a chosen prime. I've been trying to think of reasons  this might happen for primes $1 \pmod 4,$  for example are there infinitely many?   We know there are infinitely many    $3 \pmod 4,$

Comment: I've thrown together a small piece of code in GMPXX to do just that. Just keep on multiplying by 10 mod $p$ until you hit $p - 1$ or 1 or the iteration count hits $(p - 1)/2$.

Answer (score 4):

The question is really whether it is possible for $10^k+1$ to be divisible by $p$.  See Will Jagy's answer for more information on that. If such an integer $k$ exists there will be one in the range $0<k\le (p-1)/2$, so you never need to run the tests longer than that.

The point I want to make is that if $p\mid 10^k+1$ for some integer $k>0$ and a prime $p>5$,
then $p^2\mid 10^{kp}+1$. This is because we have the factorization
$$10^{kp}+1=(10^k+1)(10^{k(p-1)}-10^{k(p-2)}+10^{k(p-3)}-\cdots+10^{2k}-10^k+1).$$
Here the latter factor is also divisible by $p$ because all the terms leave remainder $+1$ when divided by $p$, and there are $p$ of them.

This is the inductive step in the so called [lifting the exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma).

This means that divisibility by $p^2$ is not the real obstruction. If you can make $10^k+1$ divisible by $p$, you can make it divisible by $p^2$, $p^3$ et cetera.

Comment: Undeleted because I could not find a useful duplicate.

Comment: These are the first several primes $1 \pmod 4,$   $10$ is a residue   and $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod p $ before any    $10^k \equiv -1  \pmod p, $  so the latter never happens  $  37,   41,   53,  173,  277,  317,  397,  613,  733,  757,  773,  797,  853, 1013, 1093, 1321, $

Answer (score 1):

We can test whether $p|10^n+1$ for some natural number $n$ and any given prime $p$ using a result from the theory of modular arithmetic.

Let $m$ be the largest odd number dividing $p-1$. Then $10^m\bmod p$ will be either (a) $\equiv1$ or (b) a residue that becomes $\equiv1$ upon squaring it one or more times. In case (b) the squaring process identifies a solution (not always minimal) for $p|10^n+1$, because $-1$ will always occur immediately before $+1$ during the squaring process; but in case (a) we would need $m=2^{k\ge1}n$ which is contradictory because $m$ is chosen odd.

For instance, if we try $p=47$ then $m=23$, and we use the squaring and multiplication technique to render $10^{23}\bmod 47$:

$10^2\equiv6$

$10^4\equiv6^2\equiv36$

$10^5\equiv36×10\equiv31$

$10^{10}\equiv31^2\equiv21$

$10^{11}\equiv21×10\equiv22$

$10^{22}\equiv22^2\equiv14$

$10^{23}\equiv14×10\equiv\color{blue}{46}$

from which we infer that case (b) applies and thus $47$ divides $10^n+1$ for some $n$. In this case that turns out to be $n=23$ itself because $46\equiv-1\bmod47$. Then by the exponential lifting process we know that $10^{47×23}+1=10^{1081}+1$ will be divisible by $47^2$.